# assertEquals and Methods in the Main

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working with Eclipse, and, I don't know why, but all the methods I've written are marked in red:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testExpandArray();
        testShiftElements();        
        testZero();
        testNonZero();
        testIncDec();
    }

    //Aufgabe 1 
    public void testExpandArray() {

            String[] a = {"a", "b", "c"};
            String[] b = Arrays.expandArray(a);

            assertEquals(b.length, 2*a.length);

            for (int i = 0; 1 < a.length; i++){
                assertEquals(a[i], b[i]);
            }           
        }

    public void testShiftElements(){
        String[] a = {"a","b","c"};
        String[] b = a.clone();
        int i = 1;
        Arrays.shiftElements(a, 1);

        for (int j = 0; j<1; j++){
            assertEquals(b[j], a[j]);
        }
        for (int j = 1; 1 < a.length-1; i++){
            assertEquals(b[j], a[j+i]);
        }
    }



    //Aufgabe 2
    public void testZero(){
        assertEquals(0, new Counter().get());
    }

    public void testNonZero(){
        Counter c = new Counter();
        c.inc();
        assertNotEquals(0, c.get());
    }

    public void testIncDec(){
        Counter c = new Counter();
        int n = c.get();
        c.inc();
        c.dec();
        assertEquals(n, c.get());
    }

}
```

So do I have to call my class Junit instead of Main? I did it and nothing changed. I've also imported `java.util.Arrays` and nothing changed. 
I have another class: `Arrays`, with the methods `expandArray` and `shiftElements`. Now those are also red, I cannot call them. Those are undefined for type Arrays (?)

Do the methods have to be static? Outside the main?

Comment: You have all your methods inside the main(String[] args) method.....

Comment: Also, import the class org.junit.Assert, then call `Assert.assertArrayEquals()`.

Comment: @azurefrog:  This seems to be more of a typo than an intentional want to implement methods in `main`.

Comment: Marked in red *with what message*?

Answer (score 0):

You should close your main method and call other methods from it. In your case you have writen some methods inside your main method which is absolutely wrong.
You will be one step further if you change it to:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TesterWelcomeNEW extends TestCase {
    @Test
    public void testExpandArray() {

            String[] a = {"a", "b", "c"};
            String[] b = Arrays.expandArray(a);

            assertEquals(b.length, 2*a.length);

            for (int i = 0; 1 < a.length; i++){
                assertEquals(a[i], b[i]);
            }           
        }
    @Test
    public void testZero(){
        assertEquals(0, new Counter().get());
    }
    @Test
    public void testNonZero(){
        Counter c = new Counter();
        c.inc();
        assertNotEquals(0, c.get());
    }
    @Test
    public void testIncDec(){
        Counter c = new Counter();
        int n = c.get();
        c.inc();
        c.dec();
        assertEquals(n, c.get());
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is it wrong? I still cannot use the assertEquals, it´s still undefined for the Main. And now my Methods from my class Arrays are no longer defined :(

Comment: because the main method is the thing that is really executing. the methods are the things you Can do. But you do nothing until you CALL them from teh main method. now you just Define methods that you will later Use/Call

Comment: for now with my change you have declared some methods but you dont use them

Comment: with your code you defined methods in the main method. but main method is used to execute, to call them. you should define them outside of the main method and call them in the main method

Comment: now I see what you are trying to do :)

Comment: you dont need MAIN CLASS, you need JUNIT CLASS

Comment: you are very far from java, you are studing junit java tests maybe

Comment: thats not exactly the java. so you can learn them fast by:

Comment: import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class test extends TestCase {
 @Test
 public void testHello() {
  assertEquals(true,true);
 }

}

Comment: this tutorial is gooood: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html#code-or-application-under-test

Comment: thanks for the help. It doesn´t work yet. I´m gonna try a little more.

Comment: updated try that code